# Is creating custom Security Token Service in Visual Studio 2015 .NET 4.5 is good idea?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I want to implement universal authentication and authorization mechanism in my company. It should be able to use Active Directory accounts, custom user database, external OAuth tokens and be ready to add another methods (maybe something like "safe VPN" accounts).

I've read a lot about Security Token Service and it is what exactly fit my needs but I've found opinions that I should use custom STS only for developing/testing purposes and in production environment I should use something like Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 or Microsoft Azure Access Control Service, but AD FS 2.0 cannot authorize users who do not exist in AD right? What is the reason that they insist to use they solutions?

In Visual Studio 2015 I could not even find tool like 'Identity and Access Tool', everything is hidden inside a Framework. So I wonder if creating custom STS based on System.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService is good idea or I don't understand actual standards? If so is anyone has some link to tutorial/example how to do it in WIF 4.5?

Comment: I can't help you with the opinions you ask for, but you might find Taiseer's website of some help: http://bitoftech.net/

Comment: I just asked the same question and amazes me there's not an easy solution to this problem, Users authenticating inside domain and users authenticating outside domain when inside users are in AD and outside users are stored in a database. I'm stuck with the same questions! All these great MS products that solve absolutely nothing with this type of scenario.

One version of VS has STS all over the place and VS 2013, 2015 has nothing ,I don't think MS can make up their mind IMHO.

Comment: After one month since I asked this question my conlusion is: VS STS class is deprecated in my opinion. There is opensource STS project called IdentityServer v3. In version 2 they were using standrad VS STS class and build nice STS on this base. But v3 offers much more flexibilty using OAuth 2.0 standard and supports OpenId connection. In IS3 you can authenticate anything in anywhere (authenticate in WCF or using Windows Authentication in a little bit tricky but possible). So I recommend to use it. It is impossible to create better solution if you do not have experience or a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found article, that really helps me. There are questions what you should ask before want to start implement your own STS: https://virtualdirectory.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/extending-adfs-to-multiple-identity-and-attribute-stores-part-2-of-2-the-tough-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Why not embrace a existing open source framework like IdentityServer 3 (http://www.thinktecture.com/identityserver)? No need to reinvent the wheel right?